# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on attempting access private CCLabelBMFont member within performselector

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access, performselector

I started a non ARC cocos2d project.

It throws error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while attempting to access private `CCLabelBMFont` member within `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
`title` is allocating in `doSomeInit` method. But somehow I can't access it in `doSomething` method.
What should I do to access its children?
I put a simple example below:

**a.h**

```
@interface IntroLayer : CCLayer {

}
@property (nonatomic,strong) CCLabelBMFont *_title;
@end
```

also tried this... no luck.
**a.h**

```
@interface IntroLayer : CCLayer {
   CCLabelBMFont *_title;
}
```

---

**a.m**

```
@implementation IntroLayer
@synthesize _title;
 .
 .
- (void)doSomeInit {
    _title = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Test Label" fntFile:"blah.fnt"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

- (void)doSomething {
    int count = 0;
    for (CCSprite* la in _title.children) { //<<<<<EXC_BAD_ACCESS ERROR THROWS HERE!!!
        la.opacity = 0;
    }
    [self addChild: _title];
}
```

---

Next relevant Question is this:
I modified
`_title = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Test Label" fntFile:"blah.fnt"];`

to

```
_title=[CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Test Label" fntFile:"blah.fnt"];  
[_title retain]; //this fixes EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
```

**But:**
Question 2: Is retain method leaking any memory?
Maybe I should release it in overidden `-(void)onExit` method?

Comment: btw: you should not name the property with an underscore. Just name it `title` and the compiler will create an instance variable named `_title` for you

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using ARC? ;)

Comment: non ARC project.
and yes there is reasons.
using an old  library that does not support ARC.

Comment: naming ?because of
I will use as a private member instead of a property.

my main Q is about convenient method of the dilemma I exposed.

Comment: which library would that be? and why not just compile that lib with arc disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method `doSomeInit`, your statement `_title = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Test Label" fntFile:"blah.fnt"];` assigns an autorelease `CCLabelBMFont` object to `_title` directly, i.e. without using the setter method. Therefore, this object is not retained, and released as soon as the app returns to the main run loop. So when `doSomething` executes, this object is released, and you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
You should use the setter method `self._title = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Test Label" fntFile:"blah.fnt"];`

Comment: interesting... didnt know that. thank you so much.to make us learn new things.